# Colour Change of a Convex Hull

Tags: plotting, color, regions, mesh, plot-themes

I have the following code to draw a convex hull.

```
P0={0,0};
P1={1,0}; 
P2={-1,0}; 
R[1]=ConvexHullMesh[{P0,P1,P3},Frame-> True,PlotRange->Automatic ]
Show[Region[R[1],PlotRange->{{-1.2,1.2},{-1.2,1.2}},Axes->True,ImageSize->Medium],Graphics[Text["(0,0)",{0,0}]],Graphics[Text["(0,1)",{0,1}]],Graphics[Text["(1,0)",{1,0}]],Graphics[Text["Choice [1,2] and [6,2]",{0.7,1}]]]
```

Now I want to change the color of the convex hull. I tried PlotStyle but it was not working. Can you suggest me an option to change the color from the default light blue? I'm very new to drawing plots in Mathematica. You can also give me advice on how to improve my drawing for future. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To style primitives in a `MeshRegion` object you can use [`MeshCellStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellStyle.html):

```
P0 = {0, 0};
P1 = {1, 0};
P2 = {0, 1};
R[1] = ConvexHullMesh[{P0, P1, P2}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Opacity[.5, Red]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[Region[R[1], PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Medium], Graphics[Text["(0,0)", {0, 0}]],
  Graphics[Text["(0,1)", {0, 1}]], Graphics[Text["(1,0)", {1, 0}]], 
 Graphics[Text["Choice [1,2] and [6,2]", {0.7, 1}]]]
```

[image]

An alternative way to add text labels using the options [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) and [`MeshCellShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCellShapeFunction.html):

```
ConvexHullMesh[{P0, P1, P2}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Opacity[.5, Red]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
 MeshCellShapeFunction -> 
    {{0, 1 | 2} -> (Text[Style[Round@#, Opacity[1], Black, 12], #, {0, 1.2}] &),
     {0, 3} -> (Text[Style[Round@#, Opacity[1], Black, 12], #, {0, -1.2}] &)}, 
 Epilog -> Text["Choice [1,2] and [6,2]", {0.7, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it also possible to increase the font size of the axis coordinates? Because when I make the plot smaller it is hard to read the coordinates unless we zoom in.

Comment: @Sumit, you can add the option `FrameTicksStyle -> 14` or the option `LabelStyle -> 14` .

Comment: Thanks. It worked.